# targeting a single value of a dichotomous variable in R

Tags: r, variables, target

I am trying to use the command `assocstats()` in order to receive Cramer's V for 2 Variables. This is not a a problem as long as I target the entirety of both variables:

```
assocstats(table(democrat, sex))
```

Problems arise when I try to target only 1 specific value of the dichotomous variable sex, which consists of 1 and 2.

I thought that `dplyr` might be of help with the filter command, but

```
assocstats(table(democrat, filter(sex==1))
```

does not yield any results.

Does anybody know how I can target only 1 value of the variable `sex` in this case?

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and also the package that has `assocstats` function.  I  am guessing the `democrat` and `filter(sex==1)` to have different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if I am using the `Arthritis` data from `library(vcd)`, we need to `filter` the rows that matches the 'Male' (or `1` in your dataset), select the columns of interest ('Treatment', and 'Sex'), get the frequency with `table` and use `assocstats`.

```
library(vcd)
assocstats(table(Arthritis[Arthritis$Sex=='Male', c('Treatment', 'Sex')]))
```

Assuming that the OP have two vectors i.e. 'democrat' and 'sex'

```
i1 <- sex ==1
assocstats(table(democrat[i1], sex[i1]))
```